# Spring @Scheduled leak

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, memory-leaks

Good day! I have some rest application running on standalone apache tomcat. I have a simple task with @Scheduled annotation like this:

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 200000)
private void updateSettings() {
    //do some cool stuff
}
```

So when I run my application I get something like:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.scheduling.TaskScheduler' available
```

and

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService' available
```

but it works. Guess spring puts some sheduler by itself.
I tryed to fix this and in my application config class I added

```
@EnableScheduling
```

and

```
@Bean
public TaskScheduler taskScheduler() {
    return new ConcurrentTaskScheduler();
}

@Bean
public Executor taskExecutor() {

    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    taskExecutor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(false);

    return taskExecutor;
    //or  return new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor(); - nothing changes
}
```

And after I do ./shutdown on my tomcat I get warning

```
2018-01-26 21:44:02 DEBUG DisposableBeanAdapter:246 - Invoking destroy() on bean with name 
 org.springframework.context.annotation. internalScheduledAnnotationProcessor

26-Jan-2018 21:44:02.496 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [SecureChat] appears to have started a thread named [pool-4-thread-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
java.base@9.0.1/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)


  java.base@9.0.1/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport. parkNanos(LockSupport.java:234)
 java.base@9.0.1/java.util.concurrent. locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2104)
 java.base@9.0.1/java.util.concurrent. ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1131)
 java.base@9.0.1/java.util.concurrent. ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:848)
java.base@9.0.1/java.util.concurrent. ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1092)
 java.base@9.0.1/java.util.concurrent. ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
 java.base@9.0.1/java.util.concurrent. ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
 java.base@9.0.1/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
```

And as I can see - memory really leaks. What can fix this?

Ubuntu linux 16.04, apache tomcat 8.5, spring 5, java 9

UPDATE:
This is a test project - upload it to tomcat, then start/stop - youll get memory leak.

https://github.com/RedCollarPanda/spring-sheduled-bug-test

Comment: I suspect that your custom executor isn't being closed when the application context closes. Exposing it as a `ThreadPoolTaskExector` rather than a plain `Executor` may help.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?